# Command to start and stop all services in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to start and stop all services in a kubernetes cluster in way similar to how `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down` can start and stop services in a docker-compose deployment. Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a command to do this?

No, there is no such command.

> An alternate solution to stop and start service.

**1:** First way is to write a shell script to delete the service and create once needed. # It will cost you resources(CPU's, RAM, Storage, etc ).

**2:** If you are using a `deployment` resource you can `scale-out` your `replicas` to `0` and `scale-in` as needed. # Less resource utilization.

**3:** Update the `selector:` filed in your service by which not to look for your pod. # requieed a code change

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this with some simple scripting:

```sh
for name in $(kubectl get deployment -o name); do
  kubectl rollout restart "$name"
done
```

This restarts *deployments*, which in turn deletes *pods*.  *Services* (Kubernetes-internal load balancers) remain untouched.  This recipe also doesn't affect pods from other sources (from stateful sets, from jobs, bare pods) and as written only looks at the `default` namespace.  You should be able to extend this to restart other things as needed.

Note that this won't cause pods that use a `...:latest` tag to update.  If a pod is recreated on a node that already has a copy of the named image, the (old) existing image will be used as-is.  If you use image tags based on a date stamp or source control commit ID, just `kubectl apply -f` the updated deployment YAML will cause the affected pods to be recreated.

In practice I very rarely have reason to do anything so heavy-handed as the restart script shown above.  The only place is where I have a mutating admission controller and the thing it does changes, so I need to cause pods to be recreated ("I've updated the Istio version and need to upgrade the sidecar containers").